# display arbinary value in label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to add the value from my database to a label.

The value has a datatype *varbinary(max)*

```
string buF = dt.Rows[i]["BuF"].ToString();
Label3.Text = buF;
```

For this I get the output as `System.Byte[]` which is not the correct value.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class:

```
string buF = BitConverter.ToString((byte[])dt.Rows[i]["BuF"]);
Label3.Text = buF;
```

Note that this will insert hyphens between each `byte` value in the output string. If you want to remove the hyphens and/or generate a different string format then you could do something like this, for example:

```
string buF =
    "0x" + BitConverter.ToString((byte[])dt.Rows[i]["BuF"]).Replace("-", "");
Label3.Text = buF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data some sort of text encoded as binary? Then use the appropiate [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) [`GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring.aspx)`()`. You must use the same encoding type ([`ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx), [`UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx), [`Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx) etc) or build one with the appropiate [CodePage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.codepage.aspx) for whatever is in that binary field.